# i am trying to use views but layer on views confusion

Tags: ios, view, uiview

I am trying to create a subview on the main view.

adding web view and a exit button o this subview.

I am creating the exit button image via view by creating a circle and a label.

There below my code, and my button action that is the exit button's functionality does not perform.

what is wrong with this?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {


    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    [self setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8]];


    UIView *circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,20,40,40)];
    circleView.alpha = 0.5;
    circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    //self.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];


    circleView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    circleView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    circleView.layer.borderWidth = 5;

    UILabel* circleIndex = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    circleIndex.frame    = CGRectMake(13, 10, 25, 20);
    [circleIndex setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:22]];
    [circleIndex setText:@"x"];

    [circleView addSubview:circleIndex];




    UIView *alertView  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 80, 944, 600)];

    UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 944, 600)];

    NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webView loadRequest:nsrequest];


    [alertView addSubview:webView];

    UIButton *exit = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    exit.frame = CGRectMake(920, -40, 38, 38);
    [exit addTarget:self action:@selector(exitTheWebView) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
    [exit addTarget:self action:@selector(exitTheAlert) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
    [exit setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

   // exit setBackgroundImage:<#(UIImage *)#> forState:<#(UIControlState)#>

    [circleView addSubview:exit];

    [alertView addSubview:circleView];


    [self addSubview:alertView];

}
return self;
}



-(void)exitTheWebView{

[self removeFromSuperview];

NSLog(@"bitch");
[self release];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[exit addTarget:self action:@selector(exitTheWebView) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
[exit addTarget:self action:@selector(exitTheAlert) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
```

Two methods for one action on the same button,First method will not get executed since the second one rewrites the first action

Comment: it just a mistake that i forgot to delete the line. it is not the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to actions for same button like:

```
[exit addTarget:self action:@selector(exitTheWebView) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
[exit addTarget:self action:@selector(exitTheAlert) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
```

So it'll call the second action when you tap on it. Means (`exitTheAlert`)

Also change that button code to:

```
UIButton *exits = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
exits.frame = GRectMake(920, -40, 38, 38);;
exits addTarget:self action:@selector(action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[circleView addSubview:exits];
[circleView bringSubviewToFront:exits]
[circleView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

**NOTE:** `exit` is a built in keyword, so don't use keywords for your variables/objects.

Comment: the problem is actuallay a layer problem, some views are on the top of  each other that prevents handling the action. but i could not figure out.

Comment: @erdemgc: added explanation, please check now